# Scraping Data from Table Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website's table using Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

BASE_URL = "http://www.ggp.com/properties/mall-directory"

def main():
    mech = Browser()
    url = "http://www.ggp.com/properties/mall-directory"
    page1 = mech.open(url)
    html1 = page1.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)
    extract(soup1, 2007)


def extract(soup,year):
    table = soup.find("table")
    for row in table.findAll('option'):
        print row


main()
```

Row prints out:

```
<option value="184">Yakima, WA</option>
<option value="896">Yankton, SD</option>
<option value="851">Yazoo City, MS</option>
<option value="113">York-Hanover, PA</option>
<option value="87">Youngstown-Warren, OH-PA</option>
<option value="235">Yuba City, CA</option>
<option value="205">Yuma, AZ</option>
<option value="424">Zanesville, OH</option>
```

But what I need is

```
Yakima, WA
Yankton, SD
Yazoo City, MS
York-Hanover, PA
etc...
```

I've tried `row.findAll('option value')` but this doesn't work...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cobralibre/120191

Comment: use `print row.get_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
print row.getText()
```